# Outputs JobQueueName instead of ARN for an AWS::Batch::JobQueue resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-batch

Is it possible to export the `JobQueue`**`Name`** instead of the **`ARN`** of an **`AWS::Batch::JobQueue` resource** in the `Outputs` section of CloudFormation (actually `serverless.yml`)?

This is how I export the ARN:

```
Outputs:
  epJobQueueMedium:
    Description: Batch Job Queue 50 - medium priority
    Value:
      Ref: epJobQueue50
    Export:
      Name: epJobQueueMediumArn
```

• `Fn::GetAtt` does not return anything for an AWS::Batch::JobQueue [see the table in the bottom of page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html).

• `Fn::Ref` returns the Arn for an AWS::Batch::JobQueue [see table in the bottom of page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html).

Is it possible to directly obtain the `JobQueueName` for my resource in order to avoid any further split (`Fn::Split`) and select (`Fn::Select`) on the ARN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a parameter?

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: API Template
Parameters:
  JobQueueName:
    Description: The name of the job queue
    Type: String
    Default: MyJobQueueName
JobQueue:
  Type: AWS::Batch::JobQueue
  Properties:
    ...
    JobQueueName: !Ref JobQueueName
Outputs:
  epJobQueueMediumName:
    Description: The name of this job queue
    Value: !Ref JobQueueName
    Export:
      Name: epJobQueueMediumName
```

Otherwise Select/Split can be done neatly:

```
Value: !Select [ "1", !Split [ "/", !Ref epJobQueue50 ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks. By seeing the two versions I definitely choose the Select-Split option. Parameters will come later.

Comment: I will accept it when you'll fix the `Split` syntax. The first argument is the separator ;) I've just waited to check and validate your solution :)

Comment: Good call! Updated

Comment: My final (temporary) solution was to export the ARN, pass it as an environment variable to the lambda.js and do the split with node.js. Much more comfortable. The split/select solution becomes too verbose for a Job Description, since there is "a:a:a:a/NAME:tag".